# error: expected expression before 'unsigned'

Tags: c, optimization

Working with **.wav** file...
*ptr_8 and *ptr_16 - pointers to the arrays of samples.

I want make the program to declare these pointers depending on header's data (if 8 bitsPerSample --->  declare *ptr_8...)

```
if ( hdr.S1.BitsPerSample == 8 )        // Declaring array for samples. Depending
                                        // on header's data (8 or 16 bits).
    unsigned char *ptr_8;
else
    if ( hdr.S1.BitsPerSample == 16 )
        unsigned short *ptr_16;
```

**The problem** is that it writes:

```
error: expected expression before 'unsigned'
```

to the both lines (where `*ptr_8` and `*ptr_16` must be declared) though I don't see the reason of such kind of behaviour. 
Tell me what is wrong, please.

---

**UPDATE:**

As it turned out, *declaration is a compile-time concept* (see accepted answer below).

Variables have being declared while compiling so it takes the machine's resourses once and then (when you have compiled application) they are all already declared there. It means that it was one of the worst ways of trying to optimize program...

Comment: What if you replace `hdr.S1.BitsPerSample == 8` with `true`?

Comment: It writes: `'true' undeclared (first use in function)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot make variable declarations conditionally, based on runtime conditions: both variables must be declared unconditionally, even though the rest of the code is going to use only one of them.

The only way to make declarations conditional is by using preprocessor's conditional compilation, which does not look applicable, because your condition is based on the header of the file, so it's clearly a runtime one.

You can put processing in two branches of the `if`, like this:

```
if (hdr.S1.BitsPerSample == 16) {
    unsigned short *ptr_16;
    // Use ptr_16 here
} else if (hdr.S1.BitsPerSample == 8) {
    unsigned char *ptr_8;
    // Use ptr_8 here
}
// Neither ptr_16 nor ptr_8 is available here
```

Comment: In simpler words, does it means that all variables are being declared while compiling the program? 

As I understood, this is very vary bad way to optimize the program because of the fact that all variables declare while compiling the program and they cannot be declared while running the program... 
Thankx for advise!

Comment: @Julian Correct, declaration is a compile-time concept. Preprocessor gets to touch your program before the compiler, so it could help you hide some of the declarations, but after that the compiler must see all declarations that you end up using in your code. You could limit the scope of declarations by enclosing them in curly braces, but reaching the closing brace ends variable's availability.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just declare both pointers anyway and then only populate the one you want to use? Anyway, the problem is to do with scope - if you want to declare variables within an if block it needs to have curly braces and then the variables are only valid within that brace block.